Implementing Ad Blocking in React Native WebView through Native Development
As the title suggests, I’m developing a React Native app using Expo, and I’m using react-native-webview as the WebView component in RN. I would like to use third-party libraries like Ghostery or AdBlocker to block ads in the WebView. However, I found that the WebView component doesn't expose any interfaces to intercept or capture resource requests in the webpage, such as JavaScript and CSS files. Since these resource requests cannot be intercepted, I cannot use AdBlocker to perform the necessary blocking.
I have an idea: could I use native development to replace the underlying WebView components on Android and iOS, and expose a few functions for onLoadStart and onLoadEnd? These functions could then be passed as parameters to the WebView component in the RN layer. Would this solution be feasible? If so, my concern is whether the WebView component in react-native-webview is using the WebView component that I’ve replaced in the native code. If not, how should I address this?
If there’s a problem with this approach, I would love to hear if anyone has a better solution!
